Springboot Java application gives sql exception when executing docker run, but works fine outside docker
I recently migrated a Weblogic Java application to Springboot and Docker. The application runs fine when it is run outside the docker using java -jar abcapp.war, but when a docker run is executed , it gives error
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: yogi2
So it tries to connect to an Oracle Database, it is not on my machine but on a server. Again, the db connection works fine when the application is run without a docker. The issue occurs when docker run command is executed.I am using Rancher desktop 1.14.2. What can I do to resolve this?
